# Old HTML File to HTML 5 with CSS

Tags: html, css

Hey guys i have the following issue. Am using on one of my sites a very old Template but it works very well.

Now i wont to take it to HTML 5 and CSS. My issue now is that when i enter the image by css the images not will displayed.

Can anyone help me how i have to set the css that the image will been displayed.

```
<html>
    <body style="text-align:center">

<div align="center">
<!-- Anfang Layout -->
        <div style="background-image:url('0066ff/700/head.jpg'); width:800px; height:32px; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
        <div style="background-image:url('0066ff/700/main.jpg'); width:800px; background-repeat:repeat-y;">
            <div style="width:680px">
    <!-- Inhalg hier einfügen ( Anfang )--> 

        Farbe : #0066FF Breite : 700px


    <!-- Inhalg hier einfügen ( Ende   )--> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-image:url('0066ff/700/footer.jpg'); width:800px; height:159px; background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
    <!-- Ende Layout -->

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: initially check the relative path to those images...

Comment: Make sure you have a <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>something</title></head><body>

Comment: I did it but the image will also not displayed

Comment: Does the code `<img src='0066ff/700/head.jpg' alt=''>` work?

Comment: What is your folder structure? Like @PsyCoder said, you might need to change your file paths.

Answer (score 0):

If I take the HTML code as posted and replace the relative URLs by test URLs like `http://lorempixel.com/800/32/`, the backgrounds are shown. This proves that the problem is with your image URLs. You need to replace them by working URLs. There is nothing syntactically wrong with them; they just do not refer to anything, or they do not refer to image resources, or the image resources are broken.